# Unable to run gcc on mac

Tags: macos, gcc, ld

I am trying to compile simple C code on my system. I am running `gcc` version (4.9.2) on macOS 10.11.6.

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am unable to fix this issue. This problem is not letting me install any `./configure` packages as well since they require gcc to work.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is a program called `gcc` under macOS, it is not a real gcc compiler. It is just a Clang compiler, as you can prove easily:

```
gcc --version
```

will print:

> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir:   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

You should be able to compile and link your program by omitting the `-lgcc` flag from the command line.